# Match all occurrences with window.find()

Tags: javascript

For example if I have a web page HTML like below

```
<body>
        Hello Techies, <br>
        Techies here.
</body>
```

If I search for "Techies" using

```
 var sel = window.getSelection(); 
 sel.collapse(document.body, 0); 
 document.body.offsetHeight;
 if (window.find("Techies", true)) { 
   document.execCommand("hiliteColor", false, "YellowGreen"); 
   sel.collapseToEnd(); 
 }
```

It is Highlighting only the first occurred of the "Techies". But when I search with Ctrl+F the first occurrence will be highlighted in Dark and next occurrences will be highlighted in light color mode. How can I achieve the same with the above code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try using a `while` loop:

```
if (window.find("Techies", true)) { 
   document.execCommand("hiliteColor", false, "FirstColor");
   while (window.find("Techies", true)) {
      document.execCommand("hiliteColor", false, "SecondColor");
   }
   ...
}
```

Comment: It's not quite clear what exactly "doesn't work" in your case. My guess is that the document that you try to augment doesn't have 'contenteditable' property set on. But that's ok, as you can use 'designMode' property for that purpose - switch it on before doing 'execCommand', switch it off afterwards.